# python and php bcrypt

Tags: php, python

I was using Laravel to register the users. It uses bcrypt like so:

```
$2y$10$kb9T4WXdz5aKLSZX1OkpMOx.3ogUn9QX8GRZ93rd99i7VLKmeoXXX
```

I am currently making another script that will authenticate users from another source using python. I installed `py-bcrypt` and tried it. The format is as follows:

```
$2a$10$Vj0b0GZegbpXIIpa/lvi9OjkAFJ5zNzziVRW7yN9ssDKVQDX47XXX
```

But on python I cannot authenticate the user because of `invalid salt`.

I noticed that Laravel bcrypt uses `$2y` while python uses `$2a`. How do I get around this?

notes:

```
I used 10 rounds for both crypts.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found out that the `2a` and `2y` are very similar except for the name(prefix).

replacing `2y` of the laravel hash, to `2a` still keeps the integrity of the hash and should work properly and match the password even if you replace the identity.

In my case (question) the solution was to use `str.replace('$2y$', '$2a$')` and it all worked well.
Now the py-bcrypt accepts the hash without the error `invalid salt`.

Good Luck guys.

Comment: While this may have been the best solution when you originally posted it, you should probably accept @eduardogoncalves's more up-to-date answer now.

Answer (score 7):

Now in 2018, we are able to use a hash string from php:

```
<?php echo password_hash( "302010", PASSWORD_BCRYPT ); ?>
```

> $2y$10$20l2aC6kIyltpgWLmp80n.4itLhmoP58CU80m1
>   m/ukE8TZYJAASx.

and check it with python:

```
>>>import bcrypt
>>>bcrypt.checkpw(b'302010',b'$2y$10$20l2aC6kIyltpgWLmp80n.4itLhmoP58CU80m1
m/ukE8TZYJAASx.')
```

> True

or a hash string from python with php

```
>>>import bcrypt
>>>hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(b'302010', bcrypt.gensalt())
```

> $2b$12$tbv8bBsuQUwq0GTCW0E2GeVUiS65ESb60fRVwbaVLlR1m4iwbbOWO

```
<?php //validade hash in php
if(password_verify ( "302010", '$2b$12$tbv8bBsuQUwq0GTCW0E2GeVUiS65ESb60fRVwbaVLlR1m4iwbbOWO' )){
  echo "valid";
} else {
  echo "invalid";
} ?>
```

https://3v4l.org/ELWtU