# PHP password_verify() vs Python bcrypt.hashpw()

Tags: php, python, bcrypt, password-encryption

So, right to it.

I have setup a [simple] PHP REST API where I am receiving a hashed password via the X-API-KEY header key. This works great when interfacing with another PHP script and the phrase is hashed via PHP's password_hash() method. However, when i try to interface with the API via Python and the Requests library, the key is rejected. Here are some samples:

PHP:

```
<?php
$usrid = '123456';
$dt     = new DateTime();
$secret = "secret{$usrid}{$dt->format('Ymd')}";
$hashed = password_hash($secret, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
echo $secret."\n";
echo $hashed."\n";
echo(phpversion());
?>
```

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import bcrypt, datetime, sys
usrid = '123456' # user id
t = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
secret = "secret{usrid}{t}".format(usrid=usrid,t=t)
hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(secret, bcrypt.gensalt())
print secret
print hashed
print '%d.%d.%d' % (sys.version_info[:3])
```

The output of each of these is as follows:

```
PHP:
    secret12345620161116
    $2y$10$/WUBS2RkTlfcgPxvmqYRI.EkBD/CPgnpE9rYvOqweERgSwFeENUDO
    5.6.24

Python: 
    secret12345620161116
    $2b$11$9v/l6KglHiNgOybw1Y8jWeCFHiAfv.cguO1Qmc7Noe4azSluoBeHO
    2.7.11
```

Now, obviously they are different, that is the point, but when you pass the Python output to the PHP password_verify() function, it returns False. The PHP output verifies just fine.

There has to be something I'm missing here but, for the life of me, I cant find it. I have tried using different salt options with no success. What am I missing? Are the two just not compatible? That seems silly, if it's true.

Thank you in advanced,  you intelligent internet peoples.

**UPDATE**

[I have updated the scripts with the following 2 lines for the tests]

```
PHP: $hashed = password_hash($secret, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost'=>11]);
Python: hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(secret, bcrypt.gensalt(11))
```

And I have used this [PHP] to verify the above:

```
<?php
$secret = 'secret12345620161116';

$php    = '$2y$11$rMqK7PhWtYd3E6yqqor0K.p2XEOJqbxJSrknLLWfhqZKsbYRa1YRa'; // output from php script
$python = '$2b$11$yWzCNB4dfIIVH2FLWWEQ/efSmN/KlVmLq.MGJ54plgedE1OSQgvPu'; // putput from python script

$php_needs_rehash    = password_needs_rehash($php, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$python_needs_rehash = password_needs_rehash($python, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

echo 'php_needs_rehash: '.$php_needs_rehash."\n";
echo 'python_needs_rehash: '.$python_needs_rehash."\n";
echo "\n";

echo "php_info:\n";
print_r(password_get_info($php));
echo "\n";

echo "python_info:\n";
print_r(password_get_info($python));
echo "\n";

echo "php_verified: ".password_verify($secret, $php)."\n";
echo "python_verified: ".password_verify($secret, $python)."\n";
echo "\n";
?>
```

With the following output:

```
php_needs_rehash: 1
python_needs_rehash: 1

php_info:
Array
(
    [algo] => 1
    [algoName] => bcrypt
    [options] => Array
        (
            [cost] => 11
        )

)

python_info:
Array
(
    [algo] => 0
    [algoName] => unknown
    [options] => Array
        (
        )

)

php_verified: 1
python_verified: 1
```

So, now I'm really confused as the server still doesn't recognize my python hashed key, if I don't replace the "$2b" with "$2y" as suggested by richardhsu in the comments, that is.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what versions of PHP and Python did you test this in?

Comment: If you output `secret` in PHP and in Python before hashing, are they the same?

Comment: PHP is using `$2y$` as the "bcrypt" algorithm identifier. Apparently python uses a different identifier. Also, the next value is the cost. Different costs means a different number of cycles that the hash will repeat. Try changing the php cost to `11` like the python hash (can be set as one of the options to password_hash) and see if it lines up with the python hash minus the algorithm.

Comment: Looks like you can interchange them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329871/python-and-php-bcrypt

Comment: Play around with `$options['cost'] = 11;` in PHP as they don't seem to match.

Comment: Also, they will never come back with the same string, unless you used the same salt on both. The salt is the first 22 characters after the third `$`. If you overwrote the php salt with the same one as python, it would come back with the same result (with the exception of the algorithm identifier). Example: https://3v4l.org/JijAe

Comment: Different costs shouldn't matter, right? The `password_verify()` sees the cost in the has and validates it accordingly..What exactly are you comparing?

Comment: password_verify will just hash the password string you pass in using the algorithm, cost and salt taken from the hash passed in. Then compare the two results. If you are comparing the output of both the python/php yourself, the cost will matter as the different cost will produce a different output.

Comment: But the hashes will never be equal, regardless? I mean, you can't compare two hashes to see if they are equal (since the same string will produce different hashes every time). You can only compare the raw value with a hash, and then it will look at the hash and get the cost from it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson unless you specifically set the salt to be the same. While deprecated in the most recent version, php's password_hash does allow for setting the salt.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - So if you set the salt yourself, it will produce the same hash? I did not know that.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I posted a link to an example above (https://3v4l.org/JijAe) that shows this.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - Thanks. You live and you learn! :)

Comment: @richardhsu lol, that is totally cheating but it works

Comment: hey @kdougan, did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Technically they are both different versions of bcrypt or crypt-blowfish

in php the prefix is $2y$10$
in python the prefix is $2b$11$

This means the cost factors are slightly different 10 vs 11 respectively
in your update you have fixed the cost factors to both be 11

The other part of the prefix indicates php is using the CRYPT_BLOWFISH hashing where python is using bcrypt which is based on the Blowfish cipher.

Because of those differences the 2 passwords are not interchangeable.

Comment: The BCrypt algorithm is based on the blowfish cypher, both platforms use the same algorithm BCrypt though. A different cost factor does not make the hashes incompatible, the design of BCrypt allows to verify with different cost factors.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52010667/1717535) shows that, currently, you can interchange the passwords.

Answer (score 2):

I found `passlib` and works perfectly

you need install

```
pip install passlib
pip install bcrypt
```

a sample code

```
from passlib.hash import bcrypt

php_hashed='$2y$10$/WUBS2RkTlfcgPxvmqYRI.EkBD/CPgnpE9rYvOqweERgSwFeENUDO'
plain_secret='secret12345620161116'

bcrypt.verify(plain_secret,php_hashed)
#output True
```

Comment: I found this very useful since I was exploring options to migrate the login functionality out from an old PHP code to a new Python Microservices environment without having the users to reset their password.  This worked like a charm.. thanks